# Why do I hear "to" in quick speaking english sound like "the"?

Tags: spoken-english

[I'm looking to track down a suspect](https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/looking-to-track-down-a-suspect)

This man (Barry Allen) said "I'm looking to ..." But I can just hear "I'm looking the ..."

Sound track is in the above link.

Comment: I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWV6gMhMOyM
"Interview" can be pronounced "innerview". Actually, I heard the "to" here more like a "ne".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English speakers often pronounce the words *"to"* in two different ways. One sounds like "*too*" (like the *"oo"* sound in *"tooth"*) and the other sounds more like "*tuh*" (like the *"u"* sound in "*tugboat*"). In the audio clip you shared when the speaker says *"I'm looking to"*, they are using the latter pronunciation.

Likewise the word *"the"* is commonly pronounced in two different ways. One sounds like "*thee*" and the other sounds more like "*thuh*". So the "*to*" in the audio clip probably sounded like this latter pronunciation of "*the*".